# SOLR to ignore some terms of a phrase

Tags: solr, solrnet

Is there a way to tell SOLR to search for (for example) 80% of the phrase
"term1 term2 term3 term4"

will yeild documents with at least 3 terms.

Extra question - if such logic exists - will it work with proximity :
"term1 term2 term3 term4"~15

specifically, tried to do that with SOLR.NET

```
var queries = new List<ISolrQuery>();
//filling the list...

    new SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery(queries, SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery.Operator.OR);
```

when I ran that got SolrNet.Exceptions.InvalidFieldException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Solr directly, [this is supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28582065/612265).  I am not familiar with Solr.NET though, can anyone comment on whether this feature is supported by that client?

Comment: sounds like what I need - I'll check if that will work with tight phrase "...", and not just free clauses..

Comment: followup question - I'd like it to work alongside with proximity - Field:"Term1 Term2 Term3 Term4"~10  (with mm=3)
Meaning that find at least 3 terms with proximity 10 - I couldn't make it work...

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can find the query in such way:

```
text:(term1 term2 term3) OR text:(term1 term2 term4) OR text:(term1 term3 term4) OR text:(term2 term3 term4)
```

The code to generate this kind of query is pretty simple

Comment: yep, tried that with SOLR.NET - SolrMultipleCriteriaQuery - and got  The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.

Comment: So looks like it's just some kind of syntax error, try debugging the result query. but solr suppose to support this kind of query.